# Regex match string that ends with number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-negation

What is a regex to match a string that ends with a number for example

```
"c1234" - match
"c12" - match
"c" - no match
```

Tried this but it doesn't work

```
(?|c(?|[0-9]*$))
```

Thanks again,

The beggining string needs to be specific too

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP preg_match

Answer (score 17):

Just use

```
\d$
```

to check your string ends with a digit

If you want your string to be a "c" followed by some digits, use

```
c\d+$
```

Comment: @u what ? How are you testing that ?

Comment: @user2217084: It works for any string that ends with a digit. Have you tried it?

Comment: Regular expression c\d$

Comment: The beggining string needs to be specific too

Comment: @user2217084 Note the `+` behind the `d`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regular expression pattern

```
^c[0-9]+$
```

Comment: It's about PHP not Java.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to read comment at first and I just read the question.I just want to find the correct pattern for the questioner.Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

To match any string ending with a digit use: `[\s\S]*\d$`

```
if (preg_match('/[\s\S]*\d$/', $value)) {
   #match
} else {
  #no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"(c|C).*[0-9]$"
```

See working example: https://regex101.com/r/4Q2chL/3

Comment: This is matching `c;,:.?!$+0`

Answer (score 0):

**dynamic way would be:**

```
import re
word_list = ["c1234", "c12" ,"c"]
for word in word_list:
    m = re.search(r'.*\d+',word)
    if m is not None:
        print(m.group(),"-match")
    else:
        print(word[-1], "- nomatch")
```

RESULT:

```
c1234 -match
c12 -match
c - nomatch
```

Comment: It is a PHP question, not Python.

Comment: ops, since it wasn't mentioned in the question, gave my own suggestion :)

Comment: It was mentionned, look at the tags.